# How to smoothly animate scale in ellipse in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, animation, jquery-animate

I have code to animate ellipse, but sometimes this animate run not smooth. I use jQuery transit plugin for this to easy animate css3 [here](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)

```
function scaleAnim(id){
        $(id).transition({ scale: "+=0.3" }, 300, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ 
            $(id).transition({ scale: "-=0.2" }, 300, 'easeOutCubic', function(){                   
                $(id).transition({ scale: "+=0.2" }, 300, 'easeOutCubic', function(){ 
                    $(id).transition({ scale: "-=0.3" }, 1500, 'easeOutCubic', function(){
                        scaleAnim(id);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        scaleAnim("#waiting_ellipse");
    });

<img id="waiting_ellipse" src="Images/Ellipse.png" style="width:150px; height:150px;" alt="" />
```

Please Help, why not running smooth??

**UPDATE**
here use online test: [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hX8Wd/7/)

This problem only happens in Firefox.

Comment: Can you make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem?

Comment: @thirtydot I already update my question with demo, I dont know to use it, its not work in demo online

Comment: Here is a demo that runs, jsFiddle is being strange... http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hX8Wd/7/. I can't see anything wrong with the smoothness of the animation, unfortunately. Good luck!

Comment: @thirtydot in ff I minimize and open again its sometimes not smooth